# Adding 2 variables in a loop Bash scripting

Tags: bash, loops, csv

Hope everyone is having a nice day.
I'm new to Bash and I was playing around with a code that I came up with. What it does it takes the data in a CSV file(A simple marks sheet) and add up all the marks for each module in the csv file. The code goes like this,

```
count=-1
sum=0

while read module mark
do
    if(($count>-1))
    then
            echo "Mark is $mark"
            sum=$(( $sum + $mark ))
    fi
    count=$((count+1))
done < $1

echo $sum
```

The CSV file is like this

```
Module,Mark
A,10
B,20
c,30
D,40
E,50
```

So I'm expecting to get the sum of the marks 150 but it gives me this error and stops executing.

```
Mark is 10
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Can someone please help me out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: One-liner: `tail -n +2 input.csv | cut -d ',' -f 2 | paste -sd '+' | bc`

Comment: @SergA `awk` is probably more suited to do this instead of using multiple pipes

Comment: @SergA Can you please explain a little bit more I just started about 3 days ago I don't get what your solution says. If it is not a bother can you give me some documentation links to look up. Thanks

Comment: @Aserre I'll look up on this as well Thank you

Comment: @CodeLover, explanations:
  • `tail` - print all lines of input file (`input.csv`) started from second line (`-n +2` flag);
  • `cut` - split each line by the comma symbol (`-d ','` flag) and print only second column (`-f 2` flag);
  • `paste` - concatenate/join all lines with `+` separator. In result this utility print one line with formula `10+20+30+40+50`;
  • `bc` - calculate result for formula.

Comment: For the awk solution : `awk -F "," '{if (NR!=1){result+=$2}} END{print "Mark is " result}' input.csv`. However, explaining an awk script is a bit tricky if you are not familiar with the tool. You can find [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+beginner+tutorial) online though